# Algolia search where field in index equals to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, filter, algolia

I'm using Algolia on a Rails application for search:

```
index = Algolia::Index.new("Search_production")
results = index.search('heroku')
```

I have an attribute in that index, called `type`, that's a string.

I want to search only for records with `type` `service`.

Can I apply a filter to the Ruby Algolia search? Something like?

```
results = index.search(query, { facets: '*', facetFilter: ['type:Service' ]})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using faceting & `facetFilters` is the way to go to implemented what you're describing, aka "Faceted search"! Don't forget to configure your `attributesForFaceting` setting in your index settings.

PS: you don't need `facets: '*'` here, that's not used for the filtering but just to actually retrieve facet values.